# Xamarin Forms Android .APK vs .AAB (Bundle)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having issues with a cross-platform Xamarin Forms app I created using Visual Studio 2019 and 2022.  I use SQLite in the app.

Basically, when I set the property Android Package Format to apk and run the app on Android device or Emulator everything works fine.

But when I set the property Android Package Format to bundle (that produces .aab file), I get SQLite exception saying "Cannot Create Table Without Columns ... Does (Models.TableName) Contains Public Properties?"

I have tried different App properties for Android including Link Sdk and Users Assemblies with no luck.

Does anybody know why SQLite works in .apk package but not in bundle(.aab)?

Many thanks

BTW, all the columns in the table contains are set to public.

Comment: I tested with the official sample [Xamarin.Forms - Todo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/), but I couldn't reproduce  this problem.  Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library and works with apk or aab

https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/